# Problem with Indy, ADO and Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ado, indy

I've a problem using ADO and indy in Delphi 2009.

My project always crashes on exit when running in delphi 2009.

This can be reproduced by doing the following in delphi 2009:

1. Create a new project
2. Add TAdoConnection component to the form. Create a connection to a sql server database and set the connected property to true.
3. Add IdHttp to the uses clause of the form.
4. Run, on closing the application the error occurs every time.

This is the error details

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   Project1.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  4e787e97
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.17514
Fault Module Timestamp: 4ce7ba58
Exception Code: 4000001f
Exception Offset:   000a2562
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  2057
Additional Information 1:   d1ab
Additional Information 2:   d1ab624ec7d094c26a73530c245a3468
Additional Information 3:   d1ab
Additional Information 4:   d1ab624ec7d094c26a73530c245a3468
```

As soon as I remove IdHttp from the uses clause, no error occurs.

Anyone got any ideas as to what i can do to sort this out, or suggest a different component suite to Indy I can use for http.

Answer (score 3):

Indy is completely separate from ADO. There is no way the mere presence of the IdHTTP unit in the uses clause (especially if you are not actually using the TIdHTTP component) can cause such a crash. Something else has to be happening, and removing the IdHTTP unit is just a coincidence. You are going to have to step through the app's shutdown code to see what is really happening.

Comment: There is no application shutdown code. In the example above the only bit of code i write is adding IdHttp to the uses clause. There is something that is clashing between Indy and ADO

Comment: There is always shutdown code, even if you do not write any of your own. The RTL has shutdown code. Individual units have `finalization` shutdown code. Put a breakpoint inside your DPR file's begin/end. block, and then start stepping through the code with the debugger.  There is no conflict between Indy and ADO.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably old news now but I had exactly the same issue but had neglected to install Update Pack 4 after a reinstallation.  Do so cured the problem.